# JAXB Class Instance Listener

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb, jaxb2

What is the way to specify Class Instance based JAXB Listener (as in Entity Bean) like : afterUnmarshall , beforeMarshall but on every class instance based (by implementing any interface or by annotation).

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Person")                            // Edited
    public class Person {
        protected String name; //setter getter also implemented

        void beforeMarshall(){
         //..........
        }

        void afterUnmarshall (){  // by implementing any interface or by annotation
         //..........
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAXB will match the following method signatures for those events:

```
   // This method is called immediately after the object is created and before the unmarshalling of this 
   // object begins. The callback provides an opportunity to initialize JavaBean properties prior to unmarshalling.
   void beforeUnmarshal(Unmarshaller, Object parent);

   //This method is called after all the properties (except IDREF) are unmarshalled for this object, 
   //but before this object is set to the parent object.
   void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller, Object parent);
```

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback

Comment: Is there any need to implement interface or just only specify these method signature ?

Comment: Thanks @Blaise , works fine . Does not require to implement interface or annotation .

Comment: @userG - There is no need to implement any interface, just the method signature is fine.  There isn't an equivalent to the JPA event annotations in JAXB.

Comment: Is there also beforeMarshall() & afterMarshall() method exist , (I had applied these two marshall Listener but not working).